# Polling Variable Refresh Rate of a Monitor using python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm attempting to create a Python tool that polls or displays the real-time VRR values for a monitor that supports VRR (G-Sync or Free-Sync). The code I use to display the monitor's refresh rate, which varies depending on whether the in-game or default refresh rate is changed, is shown below. However, I wanted to poll the real-run refresh rate because it fluctuates depending on the needs of the scenes. How could I  proceed with this?

```
import tkinter as tk
import win32api


class RefreshRateMonitor(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Refresh rate:")
        self.label.pack()
        self.refresh_rate_timer = self.after(1000, self.update_refresh_rate)

    def update_refresh_rate(self):
        refresh_rate = get_refresh_rate(None)
        self.label.config(text=f"Refresh rate: {refresh_rate} Hz")
        self.refresh_rate_timer = self.after(1000, self.update_refresh_rate)

def get_refresh_rate(device_name):
    display_settings = win32api.EnumDisplaySettings(device_name, -1)
    refresh_rate = display_settings.DisplayFrequency
    return refresh_rate


app = RefreshRateMonitor()
app.mainloop()
Footer
```

Comment: What does `Footer` mean in the last line of the code?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to call `get_refresh_rate` every N seconds?

Comment: I am not convinced that Windows exposes the real-time refresh rate to user mode in any way.  The DEVMODE value you're getting is a static setting based on the display control panel.  Do you actually see that number change?

Comment: @TimRoberts - yes I do the number change - only if I change my default Refresh rate in the display setting or while changing it in-game. For eg: the DOTA2 game has the option to set the refresh rate. I wanted to read the dynamic refresh rate that changes according to the game scene.

@t

Comment: @mkrieger1 - because I copy and paste my code from my GitHub repro :) - if u want i can paste the link for the same.

get_refresh_rate - will print the default value of your display. or it ll poll the dynamic refresh rate number?

Comment: @TimRoberts - There might be some way to do that which i am trying to find.
The only condition is that it will be useful if you have a VRR-supported monitor ( G-sync or Free-sync )

Comment: `"There might be some way to do"` -- No, I don't think there is.  What good would it do you?  The value changes frame by frame.  You couldn't take any action based on the number, because by the time you build a new scene, the number would have changed.  I suspect that's all internal to the hardware and cannot be queried.

Comment: @TimRoberts - I don't need to perform any actions instead I just want to read the real-time refresh rate for internal validation purposes ( VRR )